# redux Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk

My code is working properly, but when I am trying to fetch data from backend then I am getting an error "400 bad request" don't know what's going on the wrong. Please figure out my question.

//API  ==  http://localhost:8000/api/

index.js

```
import {API} from '../backend';
import axios from 'axios';

export const getdata = () => {
    return () => {
        axios.post(`${API}addtodo`)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
        })
      
        .catch(err =>{
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
}
```

Here I am sharing my actual code where add operation is performed
Todoform.js

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import '../App.css'
import {
    FormGroup,
    Input,
    Button,
    Form,
    InputGroup,
    InputGroupAddon
} from 'reactstrap';
import {v4} from 'uuid';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {getdata, AddTodo} from '../Auth'

//redux
import {connect, useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import {addTodo} from '../Action/todo';

const TodoForm  = ({addTodo}) => {

    const [title,setTitle] = useState('')

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
 useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getdata())
    }, []);


    return(
 <Form>
           <FormGroup>
               <InputGroup>
                    <Input 
                    type='text'
                    name='todo'
                    id='todo'
                    placeholder='Your next Todo'
                    value={title}
                    onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <InputGroupAddon addonType='prepend'>
                        <Button color='primary' onClick={()=>{
                            if(title === ''){
                                return alert('please add a todo')
                            }
                            const todo = {
                                title,
                                id:v4(),
                            }
                    
                            addTodo(todo);
                    
                            setTitle('');
                        }}>
                        
                            ADD
                        </Button>
                    </InputGroupAddon>
               </InputGroup>
           </FormGroup>
       </Form>      
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({

}) 

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>({
    addTodo : todo =>{
        dispatch(addTodo(todo))
    },
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(TodoForm)
```

$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ backend $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

todo.js/router

```
router.post('/addtodo',addTodo);
```

todo.js/controller

```
exports.addTodo = (req,res) =>{
  const todo = new Todo(req.body)
  todo.save((err,todo) => {
    if(err || !todo){
      return res.status(400).json({
          err : 'NOT able to store data in database'
      })
    }
    res.json(todo);
  })
}
```

Comment: 400 Bad Request simply means you're not providing the correct data that the server needs.

Comment: can you show ${API}addtodo ?

Comment: REACT_APP_BACKEND = http://localhost:8000/api/
export const API = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND;
************** backend*********************
router.post('/addtodo',addTodo);   
exports.addTodo = (req,res) =>{
  const todo = new Todo(req.body)
  todo.save((err,todo) => {
    if(err || !todo){
      return res.status(400).json({
          err : 'NOT able to store data in database'
      })
    }
    res.json(todo);
  })
}

Comment: can you check network tab of chrome? 400 is client side error

Comment: Yes it's says "Not able to store data in DB"

Answer (score 0):

It's important to pass a second argument to `axios.post` function.

I am still confused in your `getData`  function since you're using `` axios.post(`${API}addtodo`) `` to fetch the data. Try changing the route on this one.

If you are purposely trying to make a request to `addTodo` route without a body, add `{}` as the second parameter:
`` axios.post(`${API}addTodo`, {}) ``